# tire elastic search filter by association ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have a Post model that has voters. in Elastic Search i have indexed Post so that i have following example data: `name: 'My first post', voter_ids: [1,2,3]`. I am trying to search posts so that I only get results for given voter_ids. For example if search says `1,2`, i want to get `My first post` in results since it has voter_ids 1 and 2, but if search is `1,5`, I should not see that post in my result since voter 5 never voted on that post. 
following code returns all the posts that have any of the voter_ids specified. so its like OR-ing. What i am looking is AND.

```
@posts = Post.search(load: true) do |tire|
  tire.filter :terms, :voter_ids => voter_ids
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the equivalent of this:

```
"filter" : {
    "terms" : {
        "voter_ids" : ["1", "2"],
        "execution" : "and"
    }
}
```

[From reading the elasticsearch docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-filter/) there is an `execution` parameter on a `terms` filter which you can set to be `and`.

Good luck!